# Asking all remaining processes to terminate... fail

Tags: 12.10, shutdown, reboot, debugging

Ubuntu 12.10 64 bits with Unity.
When I restart or shutdown the PC, it takes too long to do it.
It shows the line `Asking all remaining processes to terminate... [fail]` and after `Killing all remaining processes`.
How can I debug this to determine the origin of the problem?

Comment: I have similar issues that occasionally get solved with upgrades or package removals... I'd be interested to find out the errors in some log files, but I never found anything related...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 13.04 running virtual in VMware player. I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> (I didn't expect a console and it doesn't show any), and all the sudden the installation continues!

I already tried <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>break</kbd>, but this had no effect.

Comment: Sounds nonsense, but somewhy this indeed solves the problem.

Comment: @totymedli You are right. I have Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit running as a guest OS in VirtualBox on a WIndows 10 Host. Ubuntu would freeze on shutdown at 'Asking all remaining processes to terminate...'  CTRL+ALT+T did the magic. Not sure what it did but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same behaviour when using a NAS (samba share) with fixed mounting points. It was caused by some kind of race condition between the unmounting process and network-manager during termination stage on shutdown.
Here's a small workaround that fixed it for me:

Fire up a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
and paste these commands:

```
sudo mv /etc/rc0.d/S31umountnfs.sh /etc/rc0.d/K15umountnfs.sh

sudo mv /etc/rc6.d/S31umountnfs.sh /etc/rc6.d/K15umountnfs.sh
```

This simply moves the unmounting process up the priority list when shutting down or rebooting the system. At least my system is shutting down very fast again without errors.

Good luck!