# Very long shutdown delay on 13.10

Tags: power-management, lenovo, thinkpad

Whenever I shutdown or reboot, there is a very long delay (several minutes) before the system will shutdown. I was getting a nm-dispatch signal 15 so I thought the problem might be with network manager. I purged network manager but it didn't help.

The message I get while shutting down is "killing all remaining processes... [fail]" with no further information.

If I don't hit up-arrow right away, I get the Ubuntu logo dots screen and they all remain white.

There is nothing in /var/crash

Things I've tried:

- [Shutdown does not power off computer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125844/shutdown-does-not-power-off-computer)
- [Asking all remaining processes to terminate... fail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259749/asking-all-remaining-processes-to-terminate-fail)
- removing both network-manager and modem-manager
- fresh install
- disabling networking
- [How to troubleshoot slow shutdown?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/369613/how-to-troubleshoot-slow-shutdown/390185#390185)

What can I do? How can I tell what is causing the hangup?

Update:
I just did a fresh install, and this problem happens on the first reboot after the install.

Comment: The "killing all remaining processes... [fail]" still happens even after reinstallation?

Comment: Related: [13.10 Shutdown/Restart issue](http://askubuntu.com/questions/392215/13-10-shutdown-restart-issue)

Comment: Braiam: Yes immediately upon the first reboot where you have to remove the installation media. It also says "modem manager caught signal 15 shutting down.

Comment: Could this be [bug 1066484](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1066484) or [bug 1024868](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/modemmanager/+bug/1024868)?

Comment: My system is a Lenovo W700 which doesn't seem to be a supported Ubuntu model. Maybe this is causing some problems?

Comment: I'm also getting this bug even though I'm connected to the internet: http://askubuntu.com/questions/310098/ubuntu-software-center-states-no-network-connection-in-reviews-but-internet so I'm thinking this might have something to do with my network cards? I've tried uninstalling both network-manager and modem-manager and the delayed shutdown problem persists.